# How to put anchor tag in input

Tags: html, css, authentication, web, input

So in my websites login page I want the user to be sent to a page named textbox.html after they click login which is an input tag so is there any way i can put an anchor tag inside of a input tag? here is the code. The main thing here is the login.html as i have already finished index.html home page

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Pacific</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="name2"><strong>Pacific</strong></li>
                <li><a href="/index.html"> <strong>Home</strong> </a></li>
                <li><a href="/html/about.html"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="/html/contacts.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </h1>
        
    </nav>
    <h1 class="name">Pacific</h1>
    <h2 class="centre"> <a href="/login.html"><strong>Get&nbsp;Started</strong> </a></h2>
    <div>
    <p class="description"> <strong>
    Get started with pacific and manage <br>
    your projects better, Let's say you <br>
    are writing an essay for your school <br>
    or sending an important email to    <br>
    your boss.Look up the best <br>
    words to use and when to <br>
    use, Pacific corrects imperfect grammer and <br>
    spelling mistakes has a translation tool,<br>
    Paragraph tool,Bold,Italic etc <br>
    Get Started with Pacific Right Now! <br>  </strong>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html"> <strong>Home</strong> </a></li>
        <li><a href="/html/about.html"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/html/contacts.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Pacific/login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
        <img src="/img/avatar.png" class="avatar">
            <h1 class="H">Login Here</h1>
            <form>
                <p>Username</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
                <a href="#">Lost your password?</a><br>
                <a href="#">Don't have an account?</a>
            </form>
            
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face{
    src: url(/fonts/Coiny-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: Coiny;
}

body, html{
    background-image: url(/img/BackGround.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.name{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Coiny;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    
    color: black;
}

.centre{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 760px;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 570px;
}

h2 a{
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: purple;
    background-color: purple;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

.description{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 22.5px;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}


li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

li a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Coiny;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
}


a{
    border-color: purple ;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 12px;

}

nav li a {
    border-color: purple;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.name2{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    
    color: black;
}

.loginbox{
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
}

.avatar{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.H{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.loginbox p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fb2525;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffc107;
    color: #000;
}
.loginbox a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: darkgrey;
    border-style: none;
}

.loginbox a:hover
{
    color: #ffc107;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `action="textbox.html"` on the `<form>` but i don't see the point of doing that. Is this just a layout or are you actually trying to login users?

```html
<form action="http://example.com">
  <p>Username</p>
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
  <p>Password</p>
  <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login"><br>
  <a href="#">Lost your password?</a><br>
  <a href="#">Don't have an account?</a>
</form>
```